# Leer el html de los enlaces de una página

Tags: javascript, html

Me gustaría saber si saber si hay alguna manera de obtener el html de los enlaces de una página desde la página origen utilizando javascript.

Cualquier idea al respecto será bienvenida.

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes usar Selenium, iMacros, Scrapy, etc. Busca algún tutorial y si hay un problema concreto vuelve por aquí.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda, les echaré un vistazo ;<)

Comment: Este es un sitio web sobre programación pero en lugar de desarrollar tu propia aplicación de webscraping también puedes usar alguna ya existente en el mercado. Por ejemplo https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/batch-link-downloader/aiahkbnnpafepcgnhhecilboebmmolnn y también mira la página de Superuser https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website